# C++: Combining private global variables and templates

Tags: c++, templates, global-variables

Suppose there is a global variable in a translation unit. It is constant, but not compile time constant (it is initialized with an object that has a non `constexpr` constructor). It is declared `static` since it should be private to the translation unit. Obviously, that global is defined in the `.cpp` file. However, now I have added a method template to that file that needs the global variable. Since it is a method that will be used by other translation units, it has to be put into the header. However, once it is in the header it can no longer access the global variable. What is the best practice to solve this problem?

Comment: Without code this was hard to follow, but any chance you can extern the global in the same header the template is defined, and use that to provide access to the template def?

Comment: Can't you use private static variables (ie. inside a class) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, but  a little tricky way to achieve your goals:

1. The variable is private, available only to some elements.
2. Your function template can access it.

Use private static variable in a class defined in header, and make your function/class templates friend of this class.

**YourFile.h**

```
class PrivateYourFileEntities {
private:
   static const int SomeVariable;
   // ... other variables and functions
   template <class T>
   friend class A;
   template <class T>
   friend void func();
   // the rest of friends follows
};

template <class T>
void A<T>::func() {
     int a = PrivateYourFileEntities::SomeVariable;
}

template <class T>
void func() {
     int a = PrivateYourFileEntities::SomeVariable;
}
```

**YourFile.cpp**

```
const int PrivateYourFileEntities::SomeVariable = 7;
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the method declaration into .h file and method body into .cpp file like:

.h file:

```
#include <iostream>

void myfunc1();
void myfunc2();
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "myheader.h"

static int myglobalvar=90;

    void myfunc1()
    {
      cout << myglobalvar << endl;
    }

    void myfunc2()
    {
      cout << "Oh yeah" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: I guess I did not get the question but after looking at the PiotrNycz's answer I understood the question..